# Need MySQL Query or WP-CLI command to updates old URLs in Shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, mysql, wp-cli

My client's website is moved from `http` to `https`, and I have updated most of the URLs using queries in phpMyAdmin, but I have been unable to update shortcode URLs.

I have used the following query to replace the URLs in `post_content`, but it has no effect on the shortcode URLs:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'src="http://example.com', 'src="https://example.com')
WHERE post_content
LIKE '%src="http://example.com%';
```

**Update:**

The following `wp-cli` command produced a single match in the `wp_yoast_seo_links` table:

```
wp search-replace 'http://example.com' 'https://example.com' --dry-run --skip-columns=guid
```

I also tried `--all-tables` in the command, and it produced more results, but only for Wordfence and other security tables.

Any ideas on why it is not finding URLs placed via short codes?

> **Note:** Shortcodes inserted using DIVI plugin.

Comment: Have you already tried it with WP-CLI's `wp search-replace 'http://example.com' 'https://example.com'`?

Comment: @leymannx No, I do not have it installed. Does it provide more advanced find and replace functionality? Searching via SQL and phpMyAdmin return zero results after running these update commands.

Comment: Ditto to @leymannx's comment - use WP-CLI's search-replace. It will make your life MUCH easier. You can do a dry run to see what it will update before doing the real thing. It makes migrating and updating WP sites a snap.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to WPSE. Please note that 3rd party plugin related questions are off topic in WPSE. However, sometimes the same question can be asked in a different way to make it [on-topic HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I've edited your question to make it closer to being on topic on WPSE. Hopefully the moderators will reconsider.

Comment: Now about the question: **Shortcode generated links** are not always saved in  the database, so depending on how the shortcodes were created and placed on your site, it's entirely possible that the **links are generated** instead of being served from the database. If they are indeed generated, then it's likely that there are settings somewhere in that plugin to make it `https`. So I suggest you check the shortcode settings.

Answer (score 3):

You should try running WP-CLI's [`search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command.

```
$ wp search-replace 'http://example.com' 'https://example.com' --all-tables
```

---

But you said these URLs are placed from a shortcode? Then you need to find out what this shortcode actually is doing. As it not necessarily has saved the URLs to the database. Maybe it's a setting in the shortcode and then the URL gets generated accordingly? You could also dump your database (maybe with WP-CLI again: `$ wp db export test.sql`) and open that with a text editor to see if you still can find the old URL in there.

Comment: I ran the command, but no luck. See my edited question.